# Sorting a column in R ignoring numeeric sign

Tags: r, sorting

Sorry if this is a trivial question.
I wish to sort a data set with positive and negative values such that it ignore its sign. i.e it `sort` like the `abs` function but keeps the sign in output or gives the sign in additional column. e.g

```
1  -2  5  -8  -9  6
```

get sorted to

```
1 -2  5  6  -8 -9
```

or

```
1 2 5 6 8 9 
+ - + + - -
```

I tried some syntax but still cant get a compact result. Is there a inbuilt function, in R, for this?
Thanks!

Comment: if you look at `sort`, it actually calls `order` (the function you want to use directly)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `abs` and `order`

```
> x[order(abs(x))]
[1]  1 -2  5  6 -8 -9
```

Answer (score 2):

Use order for indexing:

```
x = x[order(abs(x))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may help

```
> output <- data.frame(x, sign=sign(x))
> output[order(abs(x)), ]
   x sign
1  1    1
2 -2   -1
3  5    1
6  6    1
4 -8   -1
5 -9   -1
```